# VBA Find Next Occurrence

Tags: excel, vba

Hey I'm currently writing a macro in VBA (which I'm quite new at). The macro looks at a spreadsheet and finds specific column headers. It then clears the contents of any cell containing a zero. This part of my code works exactly how I want, the only issue is that it does not hand multiple occurrences of the column header...so it finds the first header, clears the contents, and ignores the second occurrence. I have tried multiple avenues whether it be looping to find it or using the .FindNext function. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you! My code is posted below:

```
Sub DeleteRows2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim lastrow As Long
With ActiveSheet
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With


'~~>Start of First Instance
'~~>dim variables and set initial values
Dim delaymaxheader As Range
Set delaymaxheader = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A4:Z4").Find(what:="DELAY Spec Max", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
Dim delaymaxcolumn As Range
Set delaymaxcolumn = Range(Cells(5, delaymaxheader.Column), Cells(lastrow, delaymaxheader.Column))
'Set delaymaxcolumn = Range(delaymaxheader.Offset(1, 0), delaymaxheader.End(xlDown))

'~~>dim variables and set initial values
Dim delayminheader As Range
Set delayminheader = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A4:Z4").Find(what:="DELAY Spec Min", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
Dim delaymincolumn As Range
Set delaymincolumn = Range(Cells(5, delayminheader.Column), Cells(lastrow, delayminheader.Column))
'Set delaymincolumn = Range(delayminheader.Offset(1, 0), delayminheader.End(xlDown))

'~~>dim variables and set initial values
Dim phasemaxheader As Range
Set phasemaxheader = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A4:Z4").Find(what:="PHASE Spec Max", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
Dim phasemaxcolumn As Range
Set phasemaxcolumn = Range(Cells(5, phasemaxheader.Column), Cells(lastrow, phasemaxheader.Column))
'Set phasemaxcolumn = Range(phasemaxheader.Offset(1, 0), phasemaxheader.End(xlDown))

'~~>dim variables and set initial values
Dim phaseminheader As Range
Set phaseminheader = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A4:Z4").Find(what:="PHASE Spec Min", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
Dim phasemincolumn As Range
Set phasemincolumn = Range(Cells(5, phaseminheader.Column), Cells(lastrow, phaseminheader.Column))
'Set phasemincolumn = Range(phaseminheader.Offset(1, 0), phaseminheader.End(xlDown))

'~~>Loop to delete rows with zero
'~~>Dim delaycount(5 To lastrow) As Integer
For i = 5 To lastrow
If Cells(i, delaymaxheader.Column) = 0 Then
Cells(i, delaymaxheader.Column).ClearContents
End If
If Cells(i, delayminheader.Column) = 0 Then
Cells(i, delayminheader.Column).ClearContents
End If
If Cells(i, phasemaxheader.Column) = 0 Then
Cells(i, phasemaxheader.Column).ClearContents
End If
If Cells(i, phaseminheader.Column) = 0 Then
Cells(i, phaseminheader.Column).ClearContents
End If


Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Have no idea why this was down voted - so have up voted to cancel it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the FindNext method to keep going (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)
LastRow is only the last row of column A though - what happens if another column goes further?
Also `Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Range("A4:Z4")` is the same as `ActiveSheet.Range("A4:Z4")`.

```
Public Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim colAllRanges As Collection
    Dim colHeadings As Collection

    'Declared as variants as they're used to step through the collection.
    Dim vHeading As Variant
    Dim vRange As Variant
    Dim vCell As Variant

    Dim rDelayMaxHeader As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set colAllRanges = New Collection
    Set colHeadings = New Collection
    colHeadings.Add "DELAY Spec Max"
    colHeadings.Add "DELAY Spec Min"
    colHeadings.Add "PHASE Spec Max"
    colHeadings.Add "PHASE Spec Min"

    For Each vHeading In colHeadings
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A4:Z4")

            'Find the first instance of the heading we're looking for.
            Set rDelayMaxHeader = .Find(What:=vHeading, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rDelayMaxHeader Is Nothing Then
                sFirstAddress = rDelayMaxHeader.Address
                Do
                    'Resize the range from heading to last row and add it to the collection.
                    colAllRanges.Add rDelayMaxHeader.Resize(lLastRow - rDelayMaxHeader.Row + 1, 1)

                    'Find the next occurrence.
                    Set rDelayMaxHeader = .FindNext(rDelayMaxHeader)

                'Keep going until nothings found or we loop back to the first address again.
                Loop While Not rDelayMaxHeader Is Nothing And rDelayMaxHeader.Address <> sFirstAddress
            End If
        End With
    Next vHeading

    'Now to go through each cell in the range we've added to the collection and check for 0's.
    For Each vRange In colAllRanges
        For Each vCell In vRange
            If vCell = 0 Then
                vCell.ClearContents
            End If
        Next vCell
    Next vRange

End Sub
```

With the above method you can add extra columns if needed - just add another `colHeadings.Add "My New Column Header"` row in the code.

Comment: This works perfect and for once I actually understand whats going on! I've been working with code other people I work with had written and could never get a clear grasp of what was exactly going on. I really do appreciate your time Darren.